# Get full number with country code(dial code) in intl tel input

Tags: javascript, laravel, intl-tel-input

i want full number with country code in form repeater. i was tired hiddenInput field but it's work only for parent data..

```
 function PhoneDisplay(input)
{
    
    var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
        onlyCountries: ["us","in", "uk","sg","ke","ae","gb","au","nz"],
        initialCountry: "auto",
        // hiddenInput :iti.getNumber(),
       // separateDialCode:true,

        geoIpLookup: function(success, failure) {
            $.get("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=efe58ad6181234", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
                var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
                success(countryCode);
            });
        },
        utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js"
        
    });
   
   /*  var full_number = iti.getNumber();
    console.log(full_number);*/

    /* var country_code = iti.getSelectedCountryData()["dialCode"];
    var number_with_code = iti.getNumber();
    var mod_number = "(" + number_with_code.substr(0, country_code.length + 1) + ")" + number_with_code.substr(country_code.length + 1);
    console.log(mod_number); */
    
}
```

Comment: The API doesn't return the `countryCode` you're looking for. It only returns country short name.

Answer (score 1):

**There are many ways to get full number with country code, best way is this**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" />
<br><br>
Full Number :
<input id="fullNumber" type="text" name="fullNumber">

<script>
  var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
  window.intlTelInput(input, {
    separateDialCode: true,
  });

  var iti = window.intlTelInputGlobals.getInstance(input);

  input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var fullNumber = iti.getNumber();
    document.getElementById('fullNumber').value = fullNumber;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: i was tired this it give me empty values

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check and let me know if you need any help

Comment: Changing the country drop down does not reflect in `fullNumber` field